# Printer connected via wifi and seen by Windows, but printing errors out

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, printing, printer

My Canon MG6250 printer is connected to my internet box via wifi (IPv4, WPA2), and Windows sees it and installs it just fine.

I can ping it:

[image]

I can connect to its web interface:

[image]

However, whenever I try to print a document, it immediately errors out:

[image]

**If I instead connect it via an ethernet cable to my PC, printing works fine.**

What else could I do to diagnose the issue? In the past, connecting this very printer to this very computer via wifi worked just fine. What has changed since then is that I moved to another flat, and I have a different internet box/router (the "Freebox Pop").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by installing Canon's MG6250 drivers instead of using Windows-provided ones.